# Execute function daily in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this function

```
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((_req: any, res: { send: (arg0: string) => void; }) => {
    // It sends notification to a user
});
```

I want this function to be executed at **3 PM daily**. How do I schedule the function to run daily at this time ?

### Edit 1

I have a function which sends notification, name of function is **sendNotifications**, how do I call this function from a **URL** and pass payload variables `title` and `body`

Sample working code:

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.firestore
      const payload = {
        notification: {
         title: no_of_followers2,
         body: desc + '  Notification body',
         icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png',
         click_action: `https://google.com`,
        }
      };
  ... // some code
const subscriber = doc.data().token;
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload);
```

### Edit 2

My function:

```
exports.sendNoti_cal_log = functions.https.onRequest((_req: any, res: { send: (arg0: string) => void; }) => {
      const payload = {
        notification: {
         title: 'Notification Title',
         body: 'Notification body',
         icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png',
         click_action: `https://google.com`,
        }
      };
      const subscriber = "evGBnI_klVQYSBIPMqJbx8:APA91bEV5xOEbPwF4vBJ7mHrOskCTpTRJx0cQrZ_uxa-QH8HLomXdSYixwRIvcA2AuBRh4B_2DDaY8hvj-TsFJG_Hb6LJt9sgbPrWkI-eo0Xtx2ZKttbIuja4NqajofmjgnubraIOb4_";
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload)
    });
```

Now when I am calling this function from URL, it works but I don't get any response, see screenshot:

[image]

Last thing I need is, how do i pass **title** from parameter and receive it in function.

### Edit 3

My working **Https function**

```
//-------notification for calllogger
exports.sendNoti_cal_log = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: { status: (arg0: number) => { (): any; new(): any; send: { (arg0: { status: string; }): void; new(): any; }; }; }) => {
      const payload = {
        notification: {
         title: 'Notification Title',
         body: 'Notification body',
         icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png',
         click_action: `https://google.com`,
        }
      };
      const subscriber = "evGBnI_klVQYSBIPMqJbx8:APA91bEV5xOEbPwF4vBJ7mHrOskCTpTRJx0cQrZ_uxa-QH8HLomXdSYixwRIvcA2AuBRh4B_2DDaY8hvj-TsFJG_Hb6LJt9sgbPrWkI-eo0Xtx2ZKttbIuja4NqajofmjgnubraIOb4_";
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload).then((messagingResponse: any) => {
        res.status(200).send({status: "OK"})
   })

    });
```

### Edit 4 (Passing Parameters)

I have passed parameter like this in my function:

```
exports.sendNoti_cal_log = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: { status: (arg0: number) => { (): any; new(): any; send: { (arg0: { status: string; }): void; new(): any; }; }; }) => {
  const param1 = req.params.param1;    

  const payload = {
        notification: {
         title: 'Notification Title'+param1,
```

But when I am passing it from URL, it says undefined in the notification:

I am passing it like this -

```
https://us-central1-fir-crud-5b378.cloudfunctions.net/sendNoti_cal_log?param1=Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update following your second update:

As you will read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions):

> Always end an HTTP function with `send()`, `redirect()`, or `end()`.
>   Otherwise, your function might continue to run and be forcibly
>   terminated by the system. See also [Sync, Async and Promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

So you need to do something like:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload)
then(messagingResponse => {
     res.status(200).send({status: "OK"});
})
```

---

For your question: "how do i pass title from parameter and receive it in function."

It is explained below in my first update ("In order to pass variables to an HTTP Cloud Function....").

### Update following your comment and update:

The URL of your Cloud Function will be as follows:

```
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/webhook
```

as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function) in the doc.

In order to pass variables to an HTTP Cloud Function and get them in the CF, you should use the [`Request`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object which "gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client" (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request) in the doc).

For example, you can use the `params` property as follows to get query string parameters:

```
exports.webhook = functions.https.onRequest((_req: any, res: { send: (arg0: string) => void; }) => {
    const param1 = _req.params.param1;
});
```

---

### Initial answer:

Your Cloud Function is an [HTTPS one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) which needs to be triggered through an HTTP request made from the "external world" to the Cloud Function platform.

So you need to schedule it from the caller/consumer end (for example a CRON service like https://cron-job.org/en/ which would issue an HTTP request to the corresponding Cloud Function URL, or one of your server, etc.).

---

If you want the Cloud Function platform to execute a specific Cloud Function at 3 PM daily, you should use a [Scheduled Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) as follows:

```
exports.webhook = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 15 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  // It sends notification to a user
  // return ...;
});
```

Note that a Scheduled Function is different from an HTTPS one (different trigger mechanism) but the business logic it implements can be the same (in your case, the code to send a notification).

---

Comment: I have made Edit::1 to my question, I can make a cron job nut how do i call my function from url and pass variables,

Comment: thanks, i am working on this, once i am sorted i'll come back

Comment: hii, i have updated question and added `Edit::2` , please guide where i am wrong

Comment: I have updated my Edit 2, it is working but there is some issue, please see `Edit::2`

Comment: One extra question: are you using Type Script in your Cloud Function??

Comment: i believe i am not, as you can see my function code, i am getting error`Property 'status' does not exist on type '{ send: (arg0: string) => void; }'.`   ,   code -`      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload).then((messagingResponse: any) => {
        res.status(200).send({status: "OK"})`

Comment: `_req: any, res: { send: (arg0: string)`:  this is Typescript typing. If you are sure you are NOT using Typescript, declare your function as `exports.sendNoti_cal_log = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {...})`?

Comment: Finally I can see function getting executed and sending back response. I updated to Edit::3 , please guide me, what am I actually using > TS or JS for functions, bit confused. Final thing, I am going to test is the parameters, get back once I achieve that

Comment: Finally i added `parameter` in function and passed it from URL, its coming undefined. I have made the last `Edit::4 Passing Parameters` , please have a look and guide. Thanks a lot for the support.